# In this C program all intervals don't appear in the output

Tags: c, function, for-loop, user-defined-functions

Why don't all intervals  show in the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int checkprimenumbers(int i);
int main()
{
    // declar varabiels
    int n1,n2,a,Tayp;
    // input from user
    printf("Enter to integer values: ");
    scanf("%d\n%d",&n1,&n2);
    printf("Prime numbers between %d and %d are: ", n1, n2);
    // condition statment
    for (a= n1 + 1;a < n2; ++a )
    {
        Tayp = checkprimenumbers(a);
        if (Tayp == 1)
            printf("%d ", a)  ;
        
        return 0;
    }
}
// user-defined function
int checkprimenumbers(int i)
{
    int b , Type =1 ;
    for (b = 2 ; b <= i/2; ++b )
    {
        if( i%b == 0)
        {
            Type =0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return Type;
}
```

The program works but the all intervals don't show
this is the output after debugging

Enter to integer values: 12

30

Prime numbers between 12 and 30 are: 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Type initial value to 1

```
 int b,Type=1;
```

And you have to move `return 0;` right before the ending } bracket of main.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Type` is uninitialized in `checkprimenumbers`.  If the number happens to be prime, you won't return 1 but instead whatever garbage value it happened to contain.  Set `Type = 1` before starting the `for` loop.
2. In `main`, the `return 0;` is inside the `for` loop, so the program will exit after checking the first number.  Move `return 0;` after the closing brace of the `for` loop.